# Convergence and divergence of $\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{z^{2^j}}{1 - z^{2^{j+1}}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

Looking over old course notes I found this problem which I couldn't figure out. Let $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $z^{2^j} \neq 1$ for all positive integer $j$. Show that
$$\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{z^{2^j}}{1 - z^{2^{j+1}}}$$
converges to $\frac{z}{1-z}$ for $\vert z \vert < 1$, to $\frac{1}{1-z}$ for $\vert z \vert > 1$, and diverges for $\vert z \vert = 1$. My only idea so far is to notice that the denominator is a difference of squares, so
$$\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{z^{2^j}}{1 - z^{2^{j+1}}} = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{z^{2^j}}{(1+z^{2^j})(1 - z^{2^j})}$$
I don't yet see anything that might be useful beyond this.

Comment: Hint: $|1-z^{2j+1}| \geq 1-|z|^{2j+1}$ and  $|1-z^{2j+1}| \geq |z|^{2j+1}-1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint 1. If $|z|<1$ then
$$\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{z^{2^j}}{1 - z^{2^{j+1}}}=
\sum_{j=0}^\infty z^{2^j}\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^{k2^{j+1}}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty z^{(2k+1)2^{j}}$$
Now notice that any positive integer $n$ can be written in a unique way as the product of an odd integer and a power of $2$.

Hint 2. If $|z|>1$ then let $w=1/z$. Hence $|w|<1$ and
$$\frac{z^{2^j}}{1 - z^{2^{j+1}}}=\frac{z^{2^j}}{z^{2\cdot 2^{j}}}\frac{1}{w^{2^{j+1}}-1}=-\frac{w^{2^j}}{1-w^{2^{j+1}}}.$$